# How we can know bits size of Computing Unit in opencl

Tags: opencl, nvidia

How can know bits size of Computing Unit in Opencl?

CL_DEVICE_BIT_SIZE_COMPUTE_UNITS

Comment: Can you go into more detail what you would like to know? Your question is rather vague.

Comment: There are no such device parameter in the OpenCL API.

Comment: I want to know the computing units bits size representation?